# Android + RxJava + For Loop + Not executing all the requests

Tags: java, android, performance, rx-java

Caller Of the method,

```
 for (String name : controllerToPartitionModels.keySet())
    {
        List<PartitionModel> partitionsList = controllerToPartitionModels.get(name);
        refreshPartition(partitionsList,false);
    }
```

Method

```
 private void refreshPartition(List<PartitionModel> partitionModels, boolean isSyncAll) {
    ITModule.getITService()
            .refreshPartitionStatus(new ArrayList<>(partitionModels), isSyncAll)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    Logger.get().d(ATTActionManager.this, "Refreshing request sent successfully for list of size : " + partitionModels.size());
                }
            }, (@NonNull Throwable throwable) -> {
                Logger.get().d(ATTActionManager.this, "Error on Refresh request");
            });
}
```

Problem
If there are 2 requests that has to be sent, I sometime see only one request being sent. Meaning, even though for loop is executing twice for 2 request(HTTP), I see only one request is being sent to the server.
What is that i am doing wrong here?
Rxjava version in use : 2.2.19

Comment: How do you see the number of requests that have to be sent and the number of requests that are sent?

Comment: 1. The "for" loop will tell me how may request I have to send. 
2. If the request is sent successfully, I log here, "Logger.get().d(ATTActionManager.this,.... in the run()". I observed if there are 2 request, i see most of the times, this line is logged only once. and no exception in the stack trace. Also, If i go in debug mode, it succeeds 100% of the times.

Comment: hi Joni, any suggestions please?

Comment: Please, can you share the code of the ```refreshPartitionStatus``` method? It could be relevant as it seems to create the rx observables

Comment: io.reactivex.Completable refreshPartitionStatus(java.util.List<com.ATTCommunicator.PartitionModel> list, boolean b);

Comment: I think he means for you to add the code *inside* the `refreshPartitionStatus` function, not just the signature of the function. You should add it to the question, rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the above 2 methods to solve your problem by using `flatMapIterable`.

**Merged Solution:**

```
private void refreshPartition(Map<String, ?> controllerToPartitionModels) {

    Observable.just(controllerToPartitionModels)
            .map(controllerToPartitionModels -> controllerToPartitionModels.keySet())
            .flatMapIterable((Function<Set<String>, Iterable<String>>) name -> name)
            .map(name -> {
                boolean isSyncAll = false; // You can customise as per requirement
                return new Pair<List<PartitionModel>, Boolean>(controllerToPartitionModels.get(name), isSyncAll)
            })
            .flatMap((Function<Pair<List<PartitionModel>, Boolean>, ObservableSource<?>>) pair -> {
                        boolean isSyncAll = pair.first;
                        List<PartitionModel> partitionModels = pair.second;
                        return ITModule.getITService()
                                .refreshPartitionStatus(new ArrayList<>(partitionModels), isSyncAll)
                    }
            )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    Logger.get().d(ATTActionManager.this, "Refreshing request sent successfully for list of size : " + partitionModels.size());
                }
            }, (@NonNull Throwable throwable) -> {
                Logger.get().d(ATTActionManager.this, "Error on Refresh request");
            });

}
```

*Kindly replace `?` with the valid object type.